# sdk manager wont let me install new android platforms

Tags: android, sdk, platform

[Android studios sdk manager wont let me install new platforms, they are all greyed out and unclickable. Here is a picture:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSisL.png)

Answer (score 1):

This shows uninstalled components to install copy the path and paste it in file manager it will take you to Android SDK manager then open it(also, grant admin privilege) and done, now you can install them.

Comment: On a different computer i could go into sdk manager and the click on a android platform then install it. Why wouldnt it do that on this computer?

Comment: This problem occurs on android studio 2.3

Answer (score 1):

Change the "Android SDK Location" to another PATH with no "empty spaces". From the picture, it seems to be an empty space between "Windows" and "7". For instance, using "C:\Android\sdk" as the SDK location. I've encountered similar issues in the past with Android Studio on Windows due to empty spaces.

Answer (score 0):

First be sure that you enough space on the drive that the SDK manager installed(depending on the API number that you want to install the drive must have 20-40 GB free space).
Then after selecting all you want to install click on install packages button and at least check the accept license and press install

Answer (score 0):

[Here's and Image to demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68kog.png) I had the same problem but when I ran android studio as an **administrator** it worked for me perfectly